# bcp adding extra characters in CSV out

Tags: sql-server, linux, bcp

I'm working a bash script that has two commands:

```
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp buyerhero.dbo.PeopleEmail OUT "D:/Data/people/PeopleEmail_06272020.csv" -F2  -U<<USER>> -P<<PASSWORD>> -S<<SERVER>> -t"§" -c
gsutil cp D:/Data/people/PeopleEmail_{date}.csv gs://offrs_table_files/PeopleEmail/To_Process/PeopleEmail_06272020.csv
```

The objective is to export out data from MSSQL and upload it to Google Big Query.  The two commands above represent the preliminary.

While the commands work, I have a weird output coming from the BCP.

```
22Â§7279373929Â§LineÂ§429734616Â§1434114003Â§0Â§1Â§DataÂ§2017-07-29Â§963313836Â§Â§143414003Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§1
23Â§9097671326Â§LineÂ§4973325331659Â§1491223321237Â§0Â§1Â§DataÂ§2017-07-29Â§963383261Â§Â§149031237Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§1
24Â§9512444462Â§LineÂ§2222§5431230333372Â§0Â§1Â§DataÂ§2017-07-29Â§9852228534Â§Â§54303372Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§Â§1
```

The delimiter is §.  The Weird "A"'s that precede them are not in the table, but appear in the CSV.

I doublechecked the table in sql server, and they are not there.  The BCP command is installed on a remote linux box.

This just started happening a few days ago.
How do I troubelshoot this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the high ASCII character ( i.e > 127 ) is available in the data if self. The character that is coming up in the file is `SELECT CHAR(194)`.

You can remove this character from data (table PeopleEmail) by replacing Â with blank (`SELECT REPLACE([COLUMNNAME], CHAR(194), '')`). However, i am **not sure** whether it has any **meaning to your application** or not. So, I would suggest to **cross check and double confirm** before doing any update on table data.

You can also try using queryout by replacing character Â with blank. Something like below

```
bcp "SELECT REPLACE(COLUMN1+'§'+COLUMN2+'§'+COLUMN3+'§'+COLUMN4, CHAR(194), '') FROM [Database].[Schema].[Table]" queryout "File.csv" -U [Username] -P [Password] -S [Server]
```

Not sure how long my answer can help you. But i would be happy if it can be helpful somehow.

Comment: so it ended up close to what you suggested.  The Section icon breaks going from SQL Server to Linux BCP for some reason.  probably due to the need to convert to utf8 enroute.  That being said, I changed to pipe (I) then found the pipes in the text, and removed them.  This let me work the magic.  Thanks Mohit for getting me there.

Comment: At least my answer helped you to go with right direction and I am glad to hear that.